# Does .NET MVC accept single digit day / month strings for DateTime object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, web-applications

On the client side, I'm validating strings that will be pushed to the .NET framework and I need to know what formats will be valid and recognized by .NET Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx lists the formats recognized but doesn't answer all of my questions.

For Date:
Are single digit day/month valid?
Are 2 digit years valid?

For Time:
What formats for am/pm are valid?  Possible strings I can see are: ('a','p',' a',' p','am','pm',' am',' pm')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET can parse dates with single day/month and 2 digit years without a problem.

You need to use a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for that.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("9/1/12", "d/M/yy", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None)
```

If you want to test for multiple formats, you can pass an array of format strings as the second parameter:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("9/1/12", new [] { "d/M/yy", "dd/MM/yyyy" } 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Comment: Great!  Just the doc I was looking for and couldn't find.  Hopefully this points someone else in the right direction too.

Comment: Question though - does the code above ALSO accept "dd/mm/yyyy" forrmat or does there need to be logic in the operator to handle that flexibility?

Comment: @Brian - It will accept two digit days and months as is. But you can provide an _array_ of format string in the second parameter and they will all be test. I will post another example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DateTime parse function accepts single digit months and days and 2-digit years. I don't know about "a" for "am" off the top of my head.

But just a suggestion -- and I don't mean to be snarky here, I really mean this as a constructive suggestion: This is a question that you could answer more quickly by just writing a 5-line test program and running it and see what happens than by posting it on a forum. Then you not only wouldn't have to sit around and wait for an answer, but you could be 100% confidant that the answer was correct, and not waste time because someone posted on a wrong answer.

Comment: Fair enough Jay.  I agree with you, although it doesn't answer the question directly.  Will do next time.